# Change of Variable in velocity calculation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, physics

We know from physics that $dv=adt$

1) Why is mathematically correct to write $\frac{dv}{dt}dt=adt$ and so considering infinitesimals as numbers ?

2) I want to calculate the definite integral of dv : $\int_{v_{1}}^{v_{1}}dv$ . Now, since $dv=adt$ , i get that $\int_{v_{1}}^{v_{2}}adt$ . But it's not correct. Why i am wrong and what calculus theorems i have to use in order to correctly calculate the integral ?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: I believe the right side integral is with respect to time and not with respect to velocity, so your limits would have to change or you'd have to change variables to express dt in terms of dv. And as the limits are identical at v1 an integral should result in zero.

Comment: I'm sorry, the second integral was not written properly. I edited. However what is the technique to change the integration values ?

Answer (score 0):

The integration is correct, however you are 'integrating' over a single point yielding 0. You are not considering infinitesimals as numbers either, you are simply using Leibniz notation.

Comment: I'm sorry, the second integral was not written properly. I edited. However what is the technique to change the integration values ?

Comment: The first is also incorrect. Also the limits should probably be $t_1, t_2$ since you integrate with respect to time. But the integration is correct: $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{a\,dt} = (t_2 - t_1)a$, assuming a is a constant. So you get the speed difference between $t_1, t_2$. @Jhdoe